# Access parent module

Tags: java, android

I am splitting my project into several module for reusability purpose. 
Currently there is 3 level of module

Main activity -> list of item -> item detail

some method/variable I declared at main activity that item detail need to use it also, is that possible item detail access method/variable from list of item or main activity? or I should pull those method or variable into another module?

main activity .gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(path: ":list_of_item")
}
```

list of item .gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(path: ":item_detail")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access methods in Parent module from child Module.You can access things only if you add them as dependency to your module.

- Main activity can access both
- list_item can access itemdetail

But in your case, it's not preferred to add parent module as dependent to child as it will create circular dependency.
so to avoid that, create a common module which can be added to all the modules as dependency and move common methods/variables to it.